# URL Rewrite in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, tomcat7, httpd.conf

I have a redirect setup on my Apache server within the httpd.conf file that redirects all traffic to "server.mydomain.com" to https://server.mydomain.com/uri. Unfortunately, some users will enter https before the URL and it does not redirect, instead they get Apache error page. I want to know how can I get users who input https before the URL to be redirect to https://server.mydomain.com/uri. I believe I may have to do a rewrite but I'm not sure or know how to go about doing it. I've research about rewrite and found it should be done in the .htaccess file but when I read Apache best practice they state it should not be done within .htaccess file for security and  performance. Instead, it should be done within the config file. Since the redirection is working within the httpd.conf file, I would like to incorporate the rewrite there as well. I presume that is the correct according to Apache website. My issue is how do I go about doing this within that file. I've included the file information below. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. The server is using Tomcat 7 with Apache 2.2.15.

httpd.conf file:

```html
</IfModule>
#
ProxyPass /uri/fbs-ws ws://server.mydomain.com:8081/uri/fbs-ws
ProxyPassReverse /uri/fbs-ws ws://server.mydomain.com:8081/uri/fbs-ws

</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>

ProxyPass /uri http://server.mydomain.com:8080/uri
ProxyPassReverse /uri http://server.mydomain.com:8080/uri

Redirect permanent / https://server.mydomain.com/uri
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating a vhost for 443 and switching to http there via Rewrite?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```